# Python requests JSON parsing : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-requests

Im having this problem with a profile generator im making ..

This is my code:

```python
    print('Reading profile data')
    with open('profile_data.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    print('Profile data loaded')
    task = int(raw_input('Task Number: '))
    delay = int(raw_input('Delay (second): '))
    x = 0
    while x < task:
        x = x + 1
        randomn = random.randint(10000, 100000000)
        email2, domain = data['email'].split('@')
        email1 = email2+'+'+str(randomn)+'@'+domain
        rando1 = random.randint(15, 40)
        r = requests.post('https://forms.nvidia.eu/FP_20161221_GFN_Early_Access/process?isJs=1&returnAs=json', data={'First_Name': data['fname'], 'Last_Name': data['lname'], 'email': email1, 'Platform': 'PC', 'Age': rando1, 'region': 'en_us'})
        e = requests.get('https://forms.nvidia.eu/FP_20161221_GFN_Early_Access/process?isJs=1&returnAs=json')
        print(e)
        succ = str(r.json()['status'])
        print(succ)
        if succ == 'SUCCESS':
            print('Success! '+str(x)+' Emails signed up')
            time.sleep(delay)
        elif succ == 'VERIFY':
            print('Task '+str(x)+' Failed due to captcha. Try again later, or use proxies')
            quit()
        else:
            print('Task number '+str(x)+' failed. Trying again in '+str(delay)+' seconds.')
            time.sleep(delay)
```

This is the full log, including the error:

```python
Reading profile data
Profile data loaded
Task Number: 30
Delay (second): 0
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 1 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 2 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 3 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 4 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 5 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 6 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 7 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
SUCCESS
Success! 8 Emails signed up
<Response [503]>
SUCCESS
Success! 9 Emails signed up
<Response [503]>
SUCCESS
Success! 10 Emails signed up
<Response [501]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    succ = str(r.json()['status'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 894, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Macs-MBP:GeforceNow Mac$
```

I have tried browsing other questions on this site, but found none that were similar to my problem. You cant directly access the link to view the json data (at least i dont think you can..). This is probably a very simple question, but ill ask anyway (sorry if it is). Any help is appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this line has an issue with it:

```
r = requests.post('https://forms.nvidia.eu/FP_20161221_GFN_Early_Access/process?isJs=1&returnAs=json', data={'First_Name': data['fname'], 'Last_Name': data['lname'], 'email': email1, 'Platform': 'PC', 'Age': rando1, 'region': 'en_us'})
```

[According to the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), when you're passing in a dictionary to the post, you should use the `json` parameter instead of the `data` parameter.

I think that will help. It's hard to say, since in your case the server is returning errors (`501 Not Implemented` and `503 Service Unavailable`), but the code is acting as though they are successes. Successful server transactions should return codes in the 200 range.